# pink texture on imported model. How to re-link the texture?

Tags: texturing

Once again, the pink texture.

Here are the steps I am following:

Download a Blender-specific file from Kitbash 3D

Unzip into a clean folder. Two files show, a Blender file for the Kitbash buildings and a folder of KB3D textures.

Run Blender, open the Kitbash buildings file. Textures are pink.

Go to File >> External Data >> Find Missing Files

Locate texture folder and click on Find Missing Files

This opens the folder, listing the texture files. Click on Find Missing Files again

Result - NOTHING!

What am I doing wrong? I've followed the recommended procedure, but it just doesn't work.

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please use a descriptive title that reflects question content

Comment: Check [ask] to learn more about asking questions. Don't forget to come back to check for answers sometime and mark as accepted if one solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the file paths they are most likely not relative in the original blender file hence they wont be found. The way the blender file was packaged probably wasnt correct.

Comment: But what is the correct way to quickly re-link lots of textures which are all in the same folder?