# Packed textures not showing Blender 2.8*

Tags: texturing, materials, packed-data

Here's the file (7.5 Mb) https://www.dropbox.com/s/6hkim9hj0ntw013/NiRoadSigns_Full.blend?dl=0

I downloaded this packed Blender file, created in 2.8. When I open it none of the textures show (the usual pink colour instead). Examining the .blend file shows that the textures are packed into the file, but Blender can't find them. I've tried "Find missing files" and "Report missing files". I've tried telling blender to unpack data into external files but it gives me the error message "No Packed Files to Unpack"

So I'm at a bit of a loss.

*The textures are packed into the file. Blender can't unpack them or find them.*

Help!?

Comment: Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/165384/pink-texture-on-imported-model-how-to-re-link-the-texture?rq=1  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/131034/textures-not-showing-in-viewport-blender-2-8?rq=1

Comment: The difference between the above (https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/165384/pink-texture-on-imported-model-how-to-re-link-the-texture?rq=1) and my question is: 
The textures do not exist in the folder. They are packed in the file, so I cannot direct Blender to 'Find' the files in a folder.